# User Interface Design for Complex, Inter-Dependent Data

Tags: user-interface, usability, user-experience

I'm facing a really tricky user input problem.  I need my users to input a "tree diagram" of preferences without being overwhelmed.

For example, suppose you're building an application that handles a user's request for computer parts.  They can specify all of the parts they're looking for in this application (mobo, monitor, keyboard, CPU, etc).  The application compiles the list and sends it to the warehouse for fulfillment.

Here's where things get sticky. The warehouse may not have all the parts.  This means that the user must input all of their preferences ahead of time, including fallback plans.  For example, "If you have *this* motherboard and *this* CPU, buy them.  Otherwise, try for *that* motherboard and *that* CPU."

There is no two-way communication.  The user gets one chance to input their order before it goes to the warehouse.  That means they need to include all of their preferences in the initial order.

I know this one's awkward, but that's why I'm here.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Michael.  I'll keep the style in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI might 'reveal itself' once you've modeled the relationships between the different concepts.  Warehouse, order, computer parts, CPU, motherboard.  And modeled the process flow: create order, select components, select options, specify priority, submit order.